# How do you display a Table / DataTable with expanding widths and heights depending on the cell content? (like a HTML table behaviour)

Tags: flutter

How to get the cell width AND height of a table / datatable (or other widget) to adjust depending on the content, how do you do this in Flutter?

This is the default table behaviour in HTML and I want that in Flutter because it is the best way to fit as much data as possible in a table.

Using a `DataTable`, the widths of each cell expand based on the length of the text in the cells.  However, the cell heights (or row height) doesn't expand.

`DataTable` text truncates where the text is too long; the height of the cell is not expanded:
[image]

Using a `Table` widget, the width of the cells do not adjust depending on the length of the content.  The column widths do contract & expand but only as a fraction of the total allocated space for the widget and not depending on their content (using columnWidths & FixedColumnWidth).

Here, note how 'Medium column' has space to its right, 'Long column' should have expanded into that space:
[image]

```
class TableDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      columnWidths: {
        0: FixedColumnWidth(20),
      },
      defaultColumnWidth: FlexColumnWidth(),
      children: [
        TableRow(children: [Text('Short column'), Text('Long column'), Text('Medium column')]),
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text('1'),
            Text('Some long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display it'),
            Container(
              child: Text('Some more text'),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Container(child: Text("Short column"), width: 100)),
        DataColumn(label: Container(child: Text("Long column"), width: 100)),
        DataColumn(label: Container(child: Text("Medium column"), width: 100)),
      ],
      rows: [
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text(//
                'Some long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display it, Some long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display itSome long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display itSome long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display it')),
            DataCell(Container(child: Text('Some more text'))),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('Some long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display it')),
            DataCell(Container(child: Text('Some more text'))),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('Some long content i would like to be wrapped when column width is not enought to fully display it')),
            DataCell(Container(child: Text('Some more text'))),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/IntrinsicColumnWidth-class.html in the columnWidths property of the **Table**

Comment: That's great, thanks! (such a long question for such a short reply!)